# Opentelemetry agent auto-instrumentation not connecting web server calls to microservice calls, although traces of both are captured independently

Tags: java, instrumentation, open-telemetry, jaeger, open-telemetry-collector

I have a basic opentelemetry setup, consisting of:

1. A deployment running a tomcat web server (with otel java agent attached on runtime)
2. multiple deployments with different microservices (with otel java agent attached on all using java options)
3. a jaeger collector, supported by ES storage, and finally a jaeger query to look at the traces.

When I make calls directly on the microservices (which further call other microservices), I am able to see the expected output of traces & spans (a long succession of calls, including mongo, ES etc., including calls to different microservices, and their instrumentation too). All of this comes under  a single trace, which is totally what I expected.

Now I wanted to analyze my entire system, end-to-end, starting from the calls on the web server, ending on microservice calls.

But, what I am observing is that, the java agent on my web server just captures GET and POST calls (with the correct http target etc.), and doesn't connect the traces with the microservice calls.
I can see the HTTP request trace on tomcat server (with a duration that matches the ENTIRE call, for ex. 7s or 8s), and the microservice call trace INDEPENDENTLY, on similar timestamps, but not collectively as a single trace (as expected, web-server -> microservice -> microservice etc.)

There is no sampling on and majorly all default parameters are used. (default sampling is used, also tried "always_on" instead of parent based "always_on", but no difference)

I wanted to understand how I can fix this,

1. What may be the reason calls are not getting connected.
2. I was unable to understand how exactly the otel java agent is propagating context, and exactly when does it inject its context information (I wanted to understand this, as I noticed some filters being applied on my tomcat server, and was wondering if this may be the reason context was being lost?)

Please help me with this, and let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue you are referring to here is called context propagation. Since you are using autoinstrumentation you have to ensure that the Java application is supported by the instrumentation or you have to do this manually. Here is the supported frameworks https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/supported-libraries.md

Are your other services using a supported library? Are the other microservices instrumented with Otel in the same way?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.
Yes, the application is using widely known libraries like MongoDB, ES, etc.
Yes, I am using the exact same method of auto instrumentation for my microservices and web deployments (just a simple setup of the otel agent, no manual instrumentation).

But as far as the libraries are concerned, lets say there was even some library not supported by the agent (although the app uses widely known libraries), I don't think that would lead to the problem I'm facing of traces not being connected. I feel I'm not able to understand some link in the propagation of context

Comment: It's more about the calls going from one to another. If you are using a framework then the calls must be intercepted and injected into to add the headers. What about your collector setup? Are you using a single collector with a single backend? Probably easier to ask on the CNCF Slack :)

Comment: So wanted to confirm, like the otel agent would be propagating context using headers purely? If that is the case, then i might dig deeper into my web servlet to check if headers might be tampered with somewhere, which may be resulting into my trace connectedness being lost.